# WebSocket Connection to 'wss://mydomain' - Failed (wss)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, pusher, forge, laravel-websockets

I'm following this package intructions: https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction

I'm using laravel forge to deploy and projects works fine in localhost but doesn't work after deploying to laravel forge

[image]

Here is my code
websocket.php

```
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],
```

broadcasting.php

```
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https'
            ],
        ],
```

.env

```
PUSHER_APP_KEY=anyKey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=anySecret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

bootstrap.js

```
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: false,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
});
```

broadcasting route

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('user-{user_id}-exe', function($user, $user_id) {
    return $user->id == $user_id;
});
```

composer.json

```
"beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.12",
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "^5.0",
```

What am I doing wrong?

maybe i think this issue for "wss"

Answer (score 1):

It was solved for me

.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID="test"
PUSHER_APP_KEY="test"
PUSHER_APP_SECRET="test"
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="test"
```

at the end

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

In `broadcasting.php` file comment `useTLS`

```
'pusher' => [
  'driver' => 'pusher',
  'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
  'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
  'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
  'options' => [
    'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
    // 'useTLS' => true,
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
    'scheme' => 'http'
  ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
            'useTLS' => true,
            'scheme' => 'http',
            'curl_options' => [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            ]
        ],
    ],
```